# initialize class A static std::map<std::string, fct_pointer> with pointer to class B function

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a two static std::map declared static in class A (A.hpp) :

```
typedef bool (*fct_pointer_t)(uint8 *msg, void *other);
typedef std::map<std::string, fct_pointer_t> map_string_to_fct_t;
typedef std::map<fct_pointer_t, std::string> map_fct_to_string_t;
class A {
     static map_string_to_fct_t str_to_fct;
     static map_fct_to_string_t fct_to_str;
}
```

I need to initialize these two static std::map from A with pointers to class B functions. This is done in B.cpp file:

```
map_string_to_fct_t A::str_to_fct = {
    {"string1", &B::fct1},
    {"string2", &B::fct2},
}
map_fct_to_t A::fct_to_str = {
    {&B::fct1, "string1"},
    {&B::fct2, "string2"},
}
B::fct1(uint8* msg, void*){
...
}
B::fct2(uint8* msg, void*){
...
}
```

In order for A static member to have access to member functions of B, I declare A friend of B as follows in B.hpp file:

```
class B {
    friend class A;
    fct1(...);
    fct2(...);
}
```

Now, why do I get this error at compilation ?

```
error: could not convert [...] from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'map_string_to_fct_t {aka std::map<std::basic_string<char>, bool (*)(uint8*, void*)>}
```

Thanks for your help.

---

EDIT: WORKS BECAUSE MEMBER FUNCTIONS ARE STATIC

Another test that I did was to put fct1 and fct2 in class A as static member functions. And it worked. So class B doesn't exist anymore :

## A.hpp

```
typedef bool (*fct_pointer_t)(uint8 *msg, void *other);
typedef std::map<std::string, fct_pointer_t> map_string_to_fct_t;
class A {
     static map_string_to_fct_t str_to_fct;
     static fct1(...);
     static fct2(...);
}
```

## A.cpp

```
map_string_to_fct_t A::str_to_fct = {
     {"string1", &A::fct1},
     {"string2", &A::fct2},
}
A::fct1(uint8* msg, void*){
...
}
A::fct2(uint8* msg, void*){
...
}
```

Comment: Please repeat after me: A pointer to a non-member function is *not* the same as a pointer to a member function. I suggest you look into [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: but if I declare A friend of B, B doesn't see A member functions as its own member functions ? Sorry, I just started learning C++ some weeks ago with a background in C.

Comment: First of all, this has nothing to do with that, but rather that `fct_pointer_t` is a typename for a *non*-member function, and you attempt to use *member* functions. A member function needs an object to be called on, which non-member functions doesn't need. This object is passed as a hidden secret argument and becomes the `this` pointer inside the member function. Secondly, that's not how `friend` work, it will not make functions in one class members or parts of another class. For that you need inheritance.

Comment: Right, I didn't express it the right way. I meant as a `friend` B has access to A's member functions. I'll look into `std::function` and `std::bind` but I still don't see what is the error since there is another test I did that looks similar to me but that worked (I'll add it to the post).

Comment: Your updated version [have the same problem](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5d3979b20a3df06). Again, *a pointer to a non-member function is **not** the same as a pointer to a member function*.

Comment: The updated version worked. I forgot to specify it was static declarations of fct1 & fct2. It is now corrected.

Comment: That the functions are `static` makes a very *big* difference. To modify my mantra: A non-member function is *not* the same as a non-static member function.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Someprogrammerdude
However, I'm stuck with a problem : I need these function pointers to be usable as keys in a std::map. It seems that std::function can't be used as key in a pair (error: no match for ‘operator<’) I updated the post with an example.